# Dynamically show hide JFrame's (or JDialog's) taskbar button

Tags: java, swing

I need to implement view options like:

-display window's task bar button [on\off]

-display window in system tray [on\off]

While system tray is not a problem, the task bar button is really painful.
The problem is that I can't find a way to show\hide task bar button at runtime, only before window is shown. Both JFrame and JDialog has ways to display or not display task bar button, but they must be set\called before window visible. So I need to restart application when user changes this option.

Maybe I missed something and someone implemented this already?

My last resort is windows api...

Comment: what exactly do you want to implement? that a task bar button is shown or that the window goes into task bar?

Comment: I want to implement application's task bar button being hidden from taskbar or displayed in taskbar at runtime.